# QDesktopServices::openUrl() cannot open directory in MAC Finder

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I want the application to open a directory in finder of MAC, but it doesn't work.

It only works in Windows, not in MAC. Any solution?

UPDATE:

As @Mohammad Kanan suggests, using this syntax:

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///your_folder", QUrl::TolerantMode));

It is working, eg:

```
QString workingDir = qApp->applicationDirPath();
QString path = QString::fromLatin1("file://%1").arg(workingDir);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(path, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Ps. you can also add relative path on it, but careful on the .. and / in the string:

```
QString workingDir = qApp->applicationDirPath();
workingDir += "/../../../";
QString path = QString::fromLatin1("file://%1").arg(workingDir);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(path, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Comment: Why not use QFileDialog

Comment: QFileDialog is used for select a file or dir, isn't it? in my case, i just need to open a directory and show files on it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax on both windows and MAC :

Open a file:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///Users/myname/myfile"));
```

Browse a folder with same syntax:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///Users/myname/"));
```

**Note**,

In case file system residing on a path that contains spaces , use `TolerantMode`:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Desktop", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Comment: I don't know why, I did exactly the same way as your way for open a foler, it wasn't working. nothing happen in finder. the path of folder is correct.

Comment: The syntax you mentioned in the question is not correct, I assume you now use the syntax I provided. then, try 2 things 1) open the folder directly by finder, there might be permissions issue 2) try this modified syntax `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///your_folder", QUrl::TolerantMode));`

Comment: @Vivi, I updated the answer to be accepted in all scenarios :)

Comment: Thanks, I found out the problem...My path was not actually 'corrrect', I add relatived path in the path string, but forgot a / between..